# Change Task Status default and closed value

Tags: custom-object, custom-field, tasks

In the Task can I create a new status value and add it as Default or Closed?

When I do this the page just refreshes and nothing changes.

**New value with "Closed" marked:**

[image]

**"Completed" remains in the field marked as "Closed":**

[image]

Comment: In short, yes you can extend the Status picklist on Task. Once you add the new picklist and then click Edit on the new item in the list of Status picklists, you should expect no issue saving how you configure the field i.e Default and/or Closed.

Comment: @TSmith So, the problem is that in trying to add other values ​​like "closed" and "default", Salesforce doesn't allow it. The screen is updated and the values ​​are maintained.